# Problems concerning subspaces of $M_{n}(\mathbb{Q}) $

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, linear-algebra, kt.k-theory-and-homology, noncommutative-algebra

Let $M_{n}(\mathbb{Q}) $ denote the $n$ times $n$ matrices over the rational number field. $N$ be a subspace of  $M_{n}(\mathbb{Q}) $.Then if all the non-zero matrices in $N$ are invertible, what is the maximum the dimension of $N$ can be?

We already know that if we take  $M_{n}(\mathbb{R}) $
instead of $M_{n}(\mathbb{Q}) $ then the answer is $ \rho(n) $. where $ \rho(n) $ is Radon Hurwitz number i.e if  $ n = (2a + 1 ) 2^{c+4d} $ where $ 0 \leq c \leq 3 $ then $ \rho(n) = 2^{c} + 8d $ .

Comment: The naive idea is that, since Q is dense in R, we can approximate a subspace N defined over R by a subspace N' defined over Q, and if N' is close enough to N then it should share the property of avoiding non-zero non-invertible matrices. Have you tried to make this work?

Comment: @RP_, how should one define closeness of subspaces?  Or is it just an informal suggestion?

Comment: This seems related to your earlier question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/392878/hurwitz-radon-problem-for-mathbbq-n.  It's not a duplicate (at least I can't see how), but it might be better to figure out one question than to ask several closely related questions in succession.

Comment: @LSpice Yes, informal suggestion. However you could define it presumably by intersecting the subspace with the unit hypersphere (in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$) and taking the distance between the intersections.

Comment: This question does not have the same answer for $\mathbb Q$ as for $\mathbb R$. Let $A$ be the 3 x 3 diagonal matrix with entries (2,1,1) and let $B$ be the matrix of the linear map $(x,y,z)\mapsto (y,z,x)$, then $A$ and $B$ span such a space over $\mathbb Q$, since there is no third root of $2$ in $\mathbb Q$. However, $\rho(3)=1$.

Comment: @Zero, do you want $B : (x, y, z) \mapsto (y, z, 2x)$?  (I'm thinking of the obvious embedding of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]2)$ in $\operatorname M_3(\mathbb Q)$, but maybe you have something else in mind!)

Comment: Somehow, I am not sure that the tags are not misplaced.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Let's call this maximal dimension function $\rho_{\mathbb{Q}}:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$, i.e., $\rho_{\mathbb{Q}}(n)$ is the largest possible dimension of a subspace $N\subset M_n(\mathbb{Q})$ such that all of the nonzero elements of $N$ are invertible.

Then $\rho_{\mathbb{Q}}(n)\ge n$, as the following construction shows:  Let $p(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ that is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, and let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{Q})$ be a matrix whose characteristic polynomial is $p$.  (Such $A$ are easily constructed.)  Let $N\subset M_n(\mathbb{Q})$ be the $\mathbb{Q}$-subspace spanned by the powers of $A$.  Then $N$ is an $n$-dimensional over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $N$ is a field isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\bigl(p(x)\bigr)$, so every non-zero element of $N$ is invertible.

Meanwhile, it's easy to see that $\rho_{\mathbb{Q}}(2)\le 2$, since any $3$-dimensional subspace of $M_2(\mathbb{Q})$ contains a nonzero element with vanishing determinant.  Thus, $\rho_{\mathbb{Q}}(2) = 2$.  Moreover, as Fedor points out in his comment below, this observation extends to all $n$ because, if $N\subset M_n(\mathbb{Q})$ had dimension greater than $n$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, then $N$ would have to intersect the codimension $n$ subspace of $M_n(\mathbb{Q})$ consisting of those matrices with first column equal to $0$.  Thus, $\rho_\mathbb{Q}(n)=n$ for all $n$.

Comment: Using $\rho$ in this post is misleading as it is used differently in the question. The function over $\mathbb Q$ has no name there.

Comment: @JensReinhold:  OK.  I'll call it $\rho_{\mathbb{Q}}$.

Comment: but any space of dimension $n+1$ contains a non-zero matrix with zero first column, right?

Comment: @FedorPetrov:  Yes, indeed, which implies that $\rho_{\mathbb{Q}}(n)\le n$.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes @FedorPetrov ,@Robert  the way of proof is correct but now I am interested in the case  if all the ellements in $N$ is skew symmetric and  invertible  then what will be the maximal dimension of $N$. You can consider $ n$ is even.. Note that if we take $\mathbb{R} $ instead of $\mathbb{Q} $  then for $ n=4 $ and $n= 8 $  the answer is 3 and 7 respectively, for $ n= 6 $ there does not exist any $N $ subspace of $M_{6}(\mathbb{R}) $ such that dim$N= 5$.

Comment: Dear Sugata, this is a new question, please ask it as such.

Comment: I have edited this question @FedorPetrov  as they are related .

Comment: @SugataMandal If you edit your question after it was answered, things get confusing very fast. It is no longer clear that Robert Bryant's answer answers the whole of your original question, and it is also not clear which part of your question he is answering, because the numbering was only introduced in the edit. And then there can be multiple partial answers of which you can only accept one. So much better to keep things clean and ask a new question.

Comment: okaay I have cleaned my edited part

Comment: @SugataMandal this is an exhaustive answer to your question. You should thus accept it, and ask a new question if you wish to get an answer to a different question.

Comment: Yes thanks for suggetion  . I have already asked my question as a fresh question.

Comment: @SugataMandal:  If there is something that you find unsatisfactory about my answer to this question, could you say what it is?  Otherwise, you should accept it, so that people won't be wondering what's wrong with it.  (It's cleaner than leaving things hanging.)  Also, you might consider re-titling the question so that it reflects what it's really about.  The current title is kind of vague.

Comment: @RobertBryant actually I dont know the procedure , but  I think I already accepted your answer , I could not find any option for acceptance other than voting up .

Comment: @SugataMandal:  That's interesting.  Just voting it up does not constitute 'accepting' an answer.   My answer is certainly not officially accepted, because there's no 'green check mark' underneath the vote tally, the way there is when the question owner accepts an answer.  (For example, look at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/394526/is-this-compactness-property-for-satisfiability-on-mathbbr-consistent.)  You, as the question owner, must have some special link to click somewhere that does this, but, since I have never asked a question, I don't know what it would look like.

Comment: @SugataMandal:  I looked and found this link: https://mathoverflow.net/help/someone-answers.  Apparently, you (and only you) should see a greyed out check mark near the vote tally for an answer to your question, and what you do is just click that to turn it green, which constitutes 'accepting' that answer.